# method executes too fast for animation iOS

Tags: ios, animation, timer

I made a simple game, it's a simple board game, when players moves by turn. When turn is changes I made some animation for this. So, here how it goes: player 1 makes a move; next,  animation (changes the colour of current move pointer to player 2), next, player 2 makes a move and then colour of turn pointer is changing to player 1.

It works fine when I play player vs player, but I made a computer opponent, and it makes his move so fast, that the colour turn pointer have no time to change colour to computer turn and after computer makes a turn it must changes back to my turn color, but in fact it's all goes too fast, so I see that this colour turn pointer only show my turn.

How can I make computer opponent method works with delay or something?

I'm thinking about NSTimer, but I don't know how to do this in proper way.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard UIKit animations, you can put the code that executes your computer opponent's move inside a completion block. That way, the computer's move will only occur once a turn animation has finished. Something like this:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:0 animations:
         ^{
            //Your turn animation goes here

         } completion:^(BOOL finished){

             //The code to call your computer opponent's move code goes here

         }];
```

Comment: This idea is nice, I'll try implement it right now. May be there is a way to do this with hmm delegate or something? because my animation performed in method that's updating my UI. It make all visible things, in short. Or it's better to add animation to Action method? I know, without line of code this looks like a dark room, but in theory, better place animation away from "calculating move method"? Or there is no principle difference?